# Number of $3$ letters words from $\bf{PROPOSAL}$ in which vowels are in the middle

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of different words of three letters which can be formed from the word  $\bf{"PROPOSAL"}$, if a vowel is always in the middle are?

**My try:** We have $3$ vowels $\bf{O,O,A}$ and $5$ consonants $\bf{P,P,R,S,L}$. Now we have to form $3$ letter words in which vowels are in the middle.

First we will select $2$ consonants from $5$ consonants. This can be done in $\dbinom{5}{2}$ ways. The middle vowel can be selected in $\dbinom{3}{1}$ ways.
So the total number of ways of selecting $3$ letter words is $\dbinom{5}{2}\cdot \dbinom{3}{1}$.

Now I did not understand how can I solve after that.

Help required. Thanks

Comment: First of all, you need to account for the fact that $O$ appears twice, as does $P$: So $PAP$ and $PAP$ would count twice, instead of once (it should only count once).  Second, there's nothing ruling out the possibility that the three letter word is $OOA$, $OAO$, or $PAO$, etc. If the problem stated "three letter words where vowels must always appear [**only**] in the middle... **then** you can assume consonants must appear on the ends. But without the word **only**, that assumption is unwarranted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not **very sure** about the methodology. Please let me know if the logic is faulty anywhere.

We have $3$ slots.$$---$$
The middle one has to be a vowel. There are only two ways in which it can be filled: **O, A**.
Let us put **O** in the middle.$$-\rm O-$$
Consider the remaining letters: **O, A, $\bf P_1$, $\bf P_2$, R, S, L**. Since we will be getting repeated words when we use $\bf P_1$ or $\bf P_2$ once in the word, we consider both these letters as a single letter **P.** So, the letters now are **O, A, P, R, S, L**. We have to select any two of them (this can be done in $^6C_2$ ways) and arrange them (this can be done in $2!$ ways). So, total such words formed are $(^6C_2)(2!)=30$. Now there will be one word (**P O P**) where we will need both the **P's**. So we add that word. Total words=$31$.

Now, we put **A** in between.$$-\rm A-$$

Again proceeding as above, we have the letters **O, P, R, S, L**. Total words formed from them are $(^5C_2)(2!)=20$. We add two words (**O A O**) and (**P A P**). Thus, total words formed here=$22$

Hence, in all, total words that can be formed are $22+31=53$.

(P.S: Please edit if anything wrong.)